# R Shiny dateInput not obeying max allowed date when NA default and min allowed date

Tags: r, shiny

### Desired outcome

I want to use `shiny::dateInput()` include a date picker in my Shiny application with:

- No default date
- A minimum allowed date
- A maximum allowed date.

### Problem

The date picker does not obey the maximum allowed date.

### Minimal reprex

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dateInput("date_in", "Choose date", value = as.Date(NA), 
              min = "2019-10-20", max = "2019-10-30")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

### Similar code that works

The date picker obeys the `max` argument when:

- I remove `value = as.Date(NA)`, setting the default to today.
- I remove `min = "2019-10-20"`, removing the minimum allowed date.

### System info

- R version: 3.5.3 (edit: updated to 3.6.1, issue persists)
- RStudio version: 1.2.1335 (edit: updated to 1.2.5001, issue persists)
- Shiny version: 1.4.0

### Edit

As it turns out, the same issue occurs with `dateRangeInput()`. The following code does not obey the `max` argument.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput("date_in", "Choose date",
                   start = as.Date(NA), end = as.Date(NA),
                   min = "2019-10-20", max = "2019-10-30")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

Making either of the following changes makes the code work as expected, analogously to `dateInput()`.

- Omitting the `start` and `end` arguments (thus defaulting both to today)
- Omitting the `min` argument.

Comment: @APJ123 I just tried your reprex and the code works as intended. I am not able to choose a date beyond 2019-10-30 or earlier than 2019-10-20.

Comment: My system info:  R version 3.5.2  R Studio Pro 1.2.1335-1  Shiny 1.3.2

Comment: @AJP123 I tried your code but i can select date beyond than that. My be you can use daterangeinput

Comment: @sactyr - could be due to differences in R/Shiny version?

Comment: @Subhasish1315 - unfortunately not, as `dateInput` has features that `dateRangeInput` doesn't have. See also my amendment to the question.

Comment: I'd encourage you to post your example [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues).

Comment: @ismirsehregal - Good idea. I submitted a GitHub issue to the shiny repo at https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2679